# ISSLive Telemetry: Locking Protocol SQLite3 C++ error on query, with Javascript code updating the same SQLite3 database, all on WSL

Tags: javascript, c++, sqlite, windows-subsystem-for-linux, lightstreamer

I am trying to repeatedly update some values in C++ based on telemetry coming from a lightstreamer server. This telemetry is real-time data from the International Space Station (ISSLive), that I will be using to articulate a VR simulation model of the same. I have the VR simulation side of this covered; I just need help with the data stream. Here's a public gist of the code: https://gist.github.com/connorjak/9f853bb83559976e12c9e38811c3c0af

## Working Starting Point

The starting point of this project is the [ISS-Mimic project](https://github.com/ISS-Mimic/Mimic). Here is their (working) architecture:

(Running on Raspberry Pi)

1. Python `database_initialize.py` removes then reinitializes a SQLite3 database in `/dev/shm/iss_telemetry.db`
2. Python `GUI.py` establishes a SQLite3 connection to the same directory, applies `isolation_level = None` to the connection object
3. At some point in `GUI.py`, a Python subprocess is opened for `ISS_Telemetry.js`
4. NodeJS `ISS_Telemetry.js` establishes a SQLite3 connection to the same directory, with this line: `var db = new sqlite3.Database("/dev/shm/iss_telemetry.db", sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE | sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);`
5. `ISS_Telemetry.js` establishes a LightstreamerClient connection to the lightstreamer server, with `setSlowingEnabled(false)`
6. `ISS_Telemetry.js` listens on the Lightstreamer connection and updates the SQLite database with new data.
7. `GUI.py` goes on to repeatedly execute select queries and fetchall() to get the entirety of the telemetry every tick.

## Non-Working Current Architecture

Now, here is my architecture, with key differences in **bold**.

(Running on Windows 10 1903, **WSL with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**)

1. **C++ `ISSLIVE.cpp` calls `system(...)` to start and wait for Python `database_initialize.py`**
2. Python `database_initialize.py` removes then reinitializes a SQLite3 database in `/dev/shm/iss_telemetry.db`
3. C++ `ISSLIVE.cpp` establishes a SQLite3 connection to the same directory, **does not apply `isolation_level = None` to the connection object (can't find equivalent functionality in C API)**
4. `ISSLIVE.cpp`calls `system(...&)` to start and **not** wait for NodeJS `ISS_Telemetry.js`
5. NodeJS `ISS_Telemetry.js` establishes a SQLite3 connection to the same directory, with this line: `var db = new sqlite3.Database("/dev/shm/iss_telemetry.db", sqlite3.OPEN_CREATE | sqlite3.OPEN_READWRITE);`
6. `ISS_Telemetry.js` establishes a LightstreamerClient connection to the lightstreamer server, with `setSlowingEnabled(false)`
7. `ISS_Telemetry.js` listens on the Lightstreamer connection and updates the SQLite database with new data.
8. `ISSLIVE.cpp` goes on to repeatedly execute select queries (`sqlite3_exec(...)`) to get the entirety of the telemetry every tick. The queries are passed with a **callback to print all received table data to cout**.

## The Problem

Instead of going to the callback function and printing any data at all, `sqlite3_exec(...)` returns [error code 15: PROTOCOL (Locking Protocol error)](https://www.sqlite.org/rescode.html). This happens after exactly ten seconds.

## The Question

What should I do to debug this? I tried valgrind callgrind to pick out computation offenders, but it appears that whatever is happening is not compute-heavy (very low compute time spent in this code).

I could also try to replace this architecture with another. Should I? What would I use? I can't change the source server of this data. I had a false-start earlier with [cpp-lsclient](https://github.com/quotekio/cpp-lsclient), a C++ implementation of Lightstreamer. That repo appears to only have a partial implementation of lightstreamer.

## More Info

- isolation_level = None should relate to the `autocommit` mode in SQLite. `autocommit` mode is on currently in the C++ code; I checked.
- `database_initialize.py` finishes (and closes its connection) before anything else pertaining to the database runs
- `ISS_Telemetry.js` closes when the C++ application closes
- `ISS_Telemetry.js` appears to be working correctly; data is flowing in properly. It's possible there's still an issue in this code.
- Python 3.6.8
- NodeJS v12.13.1
- npm 6.12.1
- Javascript node-sqlite3 4.1.1 (actual sqlite library version ~3.30)
- C++ sqlite3 3.22.0
- lightstreamer-client 7.3.1
- C++14 std
- C++ code operating inside a pthread as a dynamically linked library, alongside a highly-multithreaded simulation platform

Comment: Try to execute `PRAGMA read_uncommitted = boolean;` ([docs](https://www.sqlite.org/isolation.html)) on connection as analog of `isolation_level = None`. P.S. It looks an weird architecture: the periodic run of query to get changes is no good.

Comment: @AikonMogwai Thanks! Looks like that at least changed my problem; I'll work on it some more and report back.

Comment: I added a github gist with my code now (https://gist.github.com/connorjak/9f853bb83559976e12c9e38811c3c0af)

Comment: I don't understand what is a reason to use C++ with sqlite? If you need to get a new data, just put in to console in Node.js and read stdout stream in C++ code.

Comment: I’m using SQLite at the moment with C++ because the NodeJS code is known-good. Your idea with other methods of passing from NodeJS to C++ is interesting though; I’ll try some things.

Comment: I ended up just replacing SQLite with a custom socket connection. Details are in the gist.

Comment: And is the problem solved?

Comment: @AikonMogwai Yes, the JavaScript code works fine, it was the C++ interface with SQLite that was the troublemaker. The new solution works.